# Why Does My Raster Catalog Crashes When I Try to Zoom?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, file-geodatabase, raster-catalog

I have a file geodatabase which includes a Raster Catalog.  Up until today I've had no problems with my Raster Catalog.  Now, when I pull in the Raster Catalog, I can see the footprint of my rasters.  However, when I try to zoom to a specific area expecting the raster to show up, ArcMap crashes.

What's even weirder:  When I zoom into a specific area, the raster shows up.  But everywhere else, it crashes ArcMap.  What is going on??

I'm using ArcMap Desktop 10.2.2. The geodatabase is in version 9.3.  But even after upgrading it to 10, I still had the same issues. I've also tried the Recover Geodatabase Tool, but then it converts my Raster to a Polygon Feature Class based off of the Raster Footprints.

Comment: You should file a bug report with ESRI - you've paid for this software, you should expect some service.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I'll look into filing a bug report.

Comment: This sounds like a file corruption issue. You may be able to recover a corrupted pyramid by rebuilding  it, but if it's a dead spot on the physical disk,  the problem may grow worse over time.  How frequent are your backups? You might want to put aside your oldest full backup for recovery.  Tech Support may have some diagnotic tools.